# Microsoft Excel Split Function Separate Column

Tags: excel

Hi I would like to split the range of data from cells A to range of cells B

ex:

[image: table]

I need the data which is located at the column DATA , split it with double space to column RESULT / split the right data to column result … which is I still try to figure it how to make it works as I had tried split function , delimiter it still cannot produce the result above … hope anyone can help ….

Answer (score 3):

There is many different ways to achieve that.

I assume that your table starts from A1 and that there is two whitespaces between letters in the column `DATA`.

##### By using standard Excel functions:

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("  ",A2)+1,256))
```

*Formula to put in B2 and pull all the way down*

##### By using new Excel 365 function [TEXTAFTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/fonction-textafter-c8db2546-5b51-416a-9690-c7e6722e90b4) :

`=TEXTAFTER(A2, "  ", -1)` or `=TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"  ")` as [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) suggested

*This function is available for only [Office 365 Insider](https://insider.office.com/en-us/) members.*

##### By using [Text.AfterDelimiter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/text-afterdelimiter) in PowerQuery:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "RESULT", each Text.AfterDelimiter([DATA], "  "))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

##### EDIT:

By choosing the Power Query approach, you can create a VBA button that will refresh the query whenever you want.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table1").Refresh

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: oh..how about i want to create it using vba macro , as i need to put this function to a button for end user to use ? tks so much for the help

Comment: Yes you can. Take a look at the EDIT I added to my post.

Comment: For the new 365 functions `=TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"  ")` is probably a better option. You can not only populate the entire array at once, it also does not split the text, it rather just takes the substring right after the double space.